# Не увеличивается значение id объекта (React)

Tags: reactjs

Есть код:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault()
let nextId = 3
const newObj = {
  id: nextId++,
  label: this.state.value
}
const newArray = [...this.state.list, newObj]

this.setState({list: newArray})

}
```

Не увеличивается значение nextId, в связи с чем React выдает ошибку, что элементы встречаются с одинаковым ключём.

Как побороть это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том что вы каждый раз создаете переменную nextId внутри функции handleSubmit

Объявите переменную nextId на одном уровне с вашей функций:

```
nextId = 0
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    ...
}
```

Тогда ваша функция будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const nextId = this.nextId++
    const newObj = {
        id: nextId,
        label: this.state.value
    }
    const newArray = [...this.state.list, newObj]
    this.setState({list: newArray})
}
```